# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So, I know this is a common question, but I've tried everything and can't get it to work.  When I click on it nothing happens.  Bootstrap and JQuery load.
JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qqS4F/
Code:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- /.btn -->
                    <a class="brand" href="#">S&J Bakery</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#about">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown" id="#dd">
                                <a href="#dd" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                    Menu
                                    <b class="caret"></b>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li href="#lunch">Lunch</li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li href="#cake">Cake</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#sponsers">Sponsers</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- ./nav-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-inner -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar navbar-inverse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Do you not have to init stuff with bootstrap? There is no javascript in that fiddle link.

Comment: the javascript is checked on the left side under JQuery 1.7.2.  It includes it

Comment: Oh I meant, the javascript box is empty, no onload, no initializing, just 1 empty line. I find it strange that a JS library requires no initialization of any kind.

Comment: You have `<li>` nodes with `href` attributes inside `<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">`, you're missing the `<a>` nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Tips48,

It looks like you are using a version of the bootstrap css file that doesn't account for dropdown menus. I've updated the fiddle with the correct items and it is working properly for me (see screenshot below):

[image]

In case you need the link to the css file, [here it is](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css). Also, you can grab the latest version from the main site at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html One nice feature is the "Customize" section, where you can tweak what you want/don't want in your project. Hopefully this helps.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Still no luck. I get these errors in the console:  
Viewport argument key "inital-scale:1.0" not recognized and ignored. localhost:8
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL /sj/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: I also replaced my css with yours and it stayed the same.  Going to restart the webserver

Comment: link to fiddle in screenshot: http://jsfiddle.net/qqS4F/10/; tested in FF(v15), Chrome(v26.0.1410.64) and IE10

Comment: I copied that exact code, and it didn't work.  Something must not be loading.  Any way to test whether JQuery/Bootstrap loaded?

Comment: document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function(){ if(jQuery) alert("WOOT!"); } );

just add a button with the id of "test" and you should be able to click on it. If jQuery is there, you would see an alert.

here is an example of the page with the test: http://jsfiddle.net/qqS4F/12/

Comment: No idea why tho, I have <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and don't know why it doesn't work